# Put a View in bottom of Screen

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uiview, swift2

I try to put a View to the bottom of the screen on my UiTableView. How can I do that? Now it is still the last row. I searched for it but I didnt found someting useful. I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Are you looking for footer view ?

Comment: One word: Footerview

Comment: Yes I mean Footerview. I try to put my AdMob banner to the bottem of the screen

Answer (score 4):

Please put UIView below the UITableViewCell like this.
[image]

Comment: I forgot to say that  I have a static table view with around 30 rows

Comment: @AndrewB. np, this also works for static table view.

Comment: @DavidJonker Great Answer, why isn't this answer checked as mark?

Answer (score 0):

Drag the desired view to the *bottom* of the `UITableView`'s contents, i.e. *below* all of the table's cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line inside your code for your table view cell bottom

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60))
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        return footerView
    }
```